# Need Help on this: How to Generate Service Account Key from 2021 for any Essential Version chatbot on Dialogflow to be used in the Index.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, service-accounts

*Several months ago, we have followed the following steps to generate this: There is a “Service Account Key” label next to each chatbot ID; Clicking this label will lead to the right page on Google Cloud. So several clicks will generate the json file of the  Service Account Key for that chatbot.  Then, we put this json file in the Index.js file of our app on Firebase, and these apps have been working without any problem.

*Now, we found that there is NO “Service Account Key” label next to each chatbot ID;

*We tried to follow the tutorial below to reach the above goal. But, we cannot find how to place the chabot ID in this new process to Generate Service Account Key for any Essential Version chatbot on Dialogflow
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2ha_o3q4Ik

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

We created the service account key json file following the steps as described at the page below https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#auth.